# How do I get these nav items to center?

Tags: html, css, nav

This goes without saying but I am fairly new to coding (as you can probably tell).

I'm having trouble trying to get these list items to the centre in the nav bar.

Here is the HTML

```css
#nav {
     padding: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #e69ae3;
    }
ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
li {
     float: left;
    }
 li a { 
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #9d3099
    }
li a:hover {
     background-color: #febdfb;
     color: black;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="nav">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="pack.html">Packages</a></li>
      <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
      <li><a href="cont.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `float` property from the `li` and display the `ul` as a flex container, justifying the content to the center.

```css
#nav {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e69ae3;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;            /* Added */
  justify-content: center;  /* Added */
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9d3099
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #febdfb;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="pack.html">Packages</a></li>
    <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
    <li><a href="cont.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w8gmzrop/

Answer (score 0):

You can centre an element in CSS by setting its width to 50% and setting the margin to auto. To do this, I would recommend creating a centre class and applying it the  tag.

You would then add this class to the tag like this:

```
<ul class="center">
```

All in all, the complete set of code would look like this:

```css
 #nav {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e69ae3;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a { 
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9d3099
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #febdfb;
  color: black;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
        <ul class="center">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="pack.html">Packages</a></li>
            <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
            <li><a href="cont.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?
[image]

Just 2 changes  `text-align: center;` and `display: inline-block;`

```css
#nav {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e69ae3;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a { 
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9d3099
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #febdfb;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="pack.html">Packages</a></li>
        <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
        <li><a href="cont.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the flex properties to **#nav** id **display: flex;** and **justify-content: center;**

```css
#nav {
     padding: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #e69ae3;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    li {
     float: left;
    }
    li a { 
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #9d3099
    }
    li a:hover {
     background-color: #febdfb;
     color: black;
    }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="pack.html">Packages</a></li>
    <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
    <li><a href="cont.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```